# Query returns no data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running a query to show `LastName` and `Hire_Date` and my results display the columns but do not include any data. This is an assignment for an online class and I have been waiting for my instructor to reply for 2 days.

Here is my statement he wants me to run it as a `JOIN` showing `BETWEEN` statement even though the info is in one table (`EmployeeT`):

```
SELECT LastName, Hire_Date
FROM EmployeeT, Job_TitleT
WHERE EmployeeT.Job_TitleID = Job_TitleT.Job_TitleID
AND Hire_Date BETWEEN '2003-1-1' and '2003-12-31'
```

Comment: Are you sure there is data in 2003? What is the data type of the `Hire_Date` column? Have you tried using proper ISO format and not using `BETWEEN`, e.g. `AND Hire_Date >= '20030101' AND Hire_Date < '20040101';`

Comment: Yes I have data from 1998-2003 I have tried using specific dates that are in the records but I get same results. I have not tried without hyphens doing now

Comment: same results withot the hyphens

Comment: Hire_Date data type is Date, LastName text

Comment: What does this return? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeT JOIN Job_TitleT ON EmployeeT.Job_TitleID = Job_TitleT.Job_TitleID`

Comment: No Column Name 1 0

Comment: I am confused when I ran this query I got the records    SELECT LastName, FirstName, Salary
From EmployeeT, Job_TitleT
Where EmployeeT.EmployeeID = Job_TitleT.Job_TitleID
AND Salary BETWEEN 10000.00 and 20000.00

Comment: Then again this suggests that the hire_date values are not what you think they are.

Comment: And *please*, [stop using implicit joins from the 1970s](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Try not joining to the Hire table and see what you get.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `SELECT Job_TitleID FROM EmployeeT;` Are there values or only Nulls?

Comment: He's saying that even without the join he's not returning any data with just the where clause against the date column.

Comment: If you ran a query that included an inner join predicate of `EmployeeT.EmployeeID = Job_TitleT.Job_TitleID` and got results, there is something seriously weird about this table schema or data.

Comment: @Jon I hope that was a typo.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `Hire_Date` is `DATETIME` you should do this:

```
SELECT e.LastName, e.HireDate  -- properly denote which table a column comes from
FROM dbo.EmployeeT AS e        -- use schema prefix and use meaningful aliases
INNER JOIN dbo.Job_TitleT AS t -- use proper, explicit JOINs instead of 1970s syntax
ON e.Job_TitleID = t.Job_TitleID
WHERE e.Hire_Date >= '20030101'-- this should be a filter (WHERE), not join criteria
AND e.Hire_Date < '20040101';
```

I'm avoiding `BETWEEN` because, if `Hire_Date` is `DATETIME`, it is *possible* that someone could have been hired on December 31 at 8:00 AM, and this person would be left out of your `BETWEEN` clause. [More info here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). <--- and please have your instructor read this!

If this is a date/time data type and not a string, and this query returns zero rows, then either you don't have any data from 2003, or you are running against the wrong copy of the database. Is your connection string using `AttachDbFileName` by any chance? If this is the case then it's possible that in Visual Studio you see one copy of the database and in Management Studio or wherever you're running this query, you're looking at a different (empty) copy.

This works fine for me, so something must be different for you (was trying to demonstrate using [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) but the SQL Server component is currently down):

[image]

If that doesn't work for you (please try it in `TempDB` or in some other database), then you're either looking at the wrong table, or you're misinterpreting the data.

And [here we go, a working SQLfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce798/1). Please take a close look at that and describe what is different between it and the query you're running.

Comment: I had it as Date time but I changed it to date, I did the created the database in Access and the exported to SQL. I do not know how this could be a join anyway all the data I am requesting comes from the EmployeeT table any way

Comment: The JOIN is one way to ensure that you only select employees who have a valid title. We have no idea why you'd need to do that; you'll have to ask your instructor about that.

Comment: I used your tried yours from above same results just column no records. I ca't see how I have anything wrong  I got the right results in the salary query??? 70's syntax LOL

Comment: One more time: the data in your datetime column is not what you think it is. Can you show the results of `SELECT Hire_date FROM dbo.EmployeeT;` somewhere?

Comment: Yep that shows a column of all the hire dates Hire_date
2003-10-07
2002-11-01
2000-06-01
2003-03-12
2003-04-24
2003-07-25
2003-07-12

Comment: And how about `SELECT system_type_id FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.EmployeeT') AND name = N'Hire_Date';`

Comment: When I add LastName to query is adds the column, It's the BETWEEN that gets me hung up

Comment: column system_type_id  row 1  40

Comment: this is what my instructor just posted f you don't get any data when you change the WHERE clause, this would mean that what you are specifying the in WHERE clause is eliminating the data from being picked up i.e. the WHERE condition is either wrong, or it's too restrictive. If you have mulitiple conditions in the WHERE clause, try one at a time to see which is the offending condition, and then fix it.

Comment: Thank for the help I found the problem. I went back and deleted my tables and recreated them and everything went fine, I make so many changes to the table when I am trying different things. I created a new test database to make those changes and hope to carry on with fewer problems. Thanks again! I rely on this site a lot when dong homework you guys are great!